# Radio Button Change Event Doesn't Fire Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It should be fairly simple. I am trying to implement a radio button group. When click on one radiobutton, it will append a text "test" underneath and when click on other radiobutton, the text on the first radiobutton will disappear and the second radiobutton will have the text appended on it. Also, there is a button that add the radiobutton dynamically, and a change event is added into that radiobutton. The following is my code:

The problem with this code is, when I click on the second radiobutton, the first radiobutton text doesn't disappear, and when I check on the third radiobutton, the second and first radiobutton text don't disappear.

How do I fix it?

```js
function add() {

  var cat_name = $('input.text').val();
  $('div.radioGroup').append('<div><div><input type="radio" name="cat" value="' + cat_name + '"/> ' + cat_name + '<br /></div></div>');

  var inputDOM = $('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]');

  $('input:radio[name="cat"]').on('change', function() {
    // alert(cat_name);

    console.log("");
    console.log(cat_name);
    console.log(cat_name + " ischecked is " + $('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]').is(":checked"));

    if ($('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]').is(":checked")) {
      inputDOM.parent().after("<span style='margin-left:5em'>test</span><br>");
      // alert("yes is working");
    } else {
      // alert("uncheck is working!");
      console.log("uncheck is working");
      inputDOM.parent().nextAll().remove();

    }
  });


  $('input.text').val('');


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioGroup">

</div>
<input type="text" name="text" class="text">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: I created the snippet you should have so now it is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the

```
$('input:radio[name="cat"]').on('change', function() {
```

outside the add() and use delegation:

```
$('div.radioGroup').on("change",'radio[name="cat"]',function() {
```

Possibly like this. Too late to guess what you really want

```js
function add() {

  var cat_name = $('input.text').val();
  $('div.radioGroup').append('<div><div><input type="radio" name="cat" value="' + cat_name + '"/> ' + cat_name + '<br /></div></div>');
  $('input.text').val('');
}

$('div.radioGroup').on('change', 'input:radio[name="cat"]',function() {
  var cat_name=this.name, inputDOM = $('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]');
  console.log("");
  console.log(cat_name);
  console.log(cat_name + " ischecked is " + $('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]').is(":checked"));

  if ($('input[value="' + cat_name + '"]').is(":checked")) {
    inputDOM.parent().after("<span style='margin-left:5em'>test</span><br>");
    // alert("yes is working");
  } else {
    // alert("uncheck is working!");
    console.log("uncheck is working");
    inputDOM.parent().nextAll().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioGroup">

</div>
<input type="text" name="text" class="text">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: the cat_name should be named value_name instead. It is the radiobutton's value. The selector is distinguished by value. Also, it doesn't work. Now the texts don't even disappear anymore, everything just keeps piling up. I want it when you click on other radiobutton, the first selected button appended text disappear.

Comment: I do not understand. You cannot uncheck a radio - you can uncheck a checkbox. Can you please show some image of before and after click? I would like to remove inputDOM and use $(this) as traversion anchor